# What changes are required in admob AdRequest code before publishing android app?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob

I am about to publish my app I made on unity. I have integrated admob code with my app, have tested ads on my phone, and it is working fine. But I am confused if the ads will work fine for users in other countries.

My question is: What changes need to be made in admob code before publishing the app to playstore.

I have browsed the internet and Stack Overflow, there are similar questions, but the answers are dispersed, and i fear i might miss something. I would like to have a compilation of things that need to be fixed related to admob before publishing my app. 
Here's what I know so far:
1. If I have created the UnitID in admob by adding my app manually, I need to link it to the app after it has been published.
2. I need to make changes to AdRequest code (code provided below).

```
public AdRequest createAdRequest()
   {
      return new AdRequest.Builder()
      .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)
      .AddTestDevice("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF")
      .AddKeyword("game")
      .SetGender(Gender.Male)
      .SetBirthday(new DateTime(1985, 1, 1))
      .TagForChildDirectedTreatment(false)
      .AddExtra("color_bg", "9B30FF")
      .Build();
   }
```

Here's the complete code for admob that I've used: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins/blob/master/unity/samples/HelloWorld/Assets/GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript.cs

I have not made any changes to it. Is there anything that needs to be added/deleted/changed in the `AdRequest.Builder()` to make sure the ads are relevant to the user? ( I know the argument to AddTestApp() needs to be changed, but should i remove it before publishing my app? ). And I've noticed there is no variable for "location" in this code. Would it make any difference, or does admob automatically work out the location of the user without the programmer having to worry about it?

Comment: I would remove `.AddKeyword("game").SetGender(Gender.Male).SetBirthday(new DateTime(1985, 1, 1)).TagForChildDirectedTreatment(false).AddExtra("color_bg", "9B30FF")` because you a limiting the ads that can be displayed by filtering them.

Comment: and about location? does it make a difference with or without it?

Comment: I'll add to ad answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would change:**

```
public AdRequest createAdRequest() {
   return new AdRequest.Builder()
   .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)
   .AddTestDevice("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF")
   .AddKeyword("game")
   .SetGender(Gender.Male)
   .SetBirthday(new DateTime(1985, 1, 1))
   .TagForChildDirectedTreatment(false)
   .AddExtra("color_bg", "9B30FF")
   .Build();
}
```

**To:**

```
public AdRequest createAdRequest() {
   return new AdRequest.Builder()
   .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)
   .AddTestDevice("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF")
   .Build();
}
```

This way you are not filtering your ads per say but allowing for the greatest possible fill rate.

Comment: Those two "AddTestDevice()" methods, is it possible to display only a test ad and not an actual ad that can earn for money? How can you assure? The second "AddTestDevice()"  method is where to put Admob app ID to start testing and displaying it as simulated ad. If I input again again with the wrong one (e.g. "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF") or none at all, will it be possible to display a real ad and earn money based on the no. of minutes of the ad being displayed? Why or why not?

Comment: @DavidDimalanta That ID is "fake". The OP didn't wan to post his real device ID on the internet.

Comment: I see. I was making an ad banner for the Unity 3D game using Admob and I leave with a fake ID and it showed an actual ad that can earn money. As far as I know, regardless of the programming software used, the test ad I know is something like this. (See link: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/images/android-quickstart-09.png)

Comment: You can't use a "fake" id. You have to use the one the SDK provides via logcat.

Comment: I see. Then, can I be able to run it without using two "AddTestDevice(ID)" methods?

Comment: @DavidDimalanta What are you talking about? When you use Admob ads, it will print a custom ID unique to your device. You set that in `AddTestDevice`. That's it.